# What is the best way to write this conditional program in Swift?

Tags: swift

```
let roomSize = "medium"
let sofasize = "large"

if roomSize == "large" {
    print ("can fit")
} else if roomSize == "medium" && ( sofasize == "medium" || sofasize == "small") {
    print ("can fit")
} else if roomSize == "small" && sofasize == "small" {
    print ("can fit")
} else {
    print("nope, cannot fit")
}
```

What is the optimal way to format this program in swift?

Comment: I'd go by using enum values, and enum can be easily compared then. In pseudo code: if `roomSize == .large { //can fit } else if roomSize.rawValue >= sofaSize.rawValue{ //can fit} else {// cannot fit}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one of the possible ideas:

```
enum MySize: Int {
    case small = 1, medium = 2, large = 3
}

let myRoomSize: MySize = .medium
let mySofaSize: MySize = .large

if mySofaSize.rawValue <= myRoomSize.rawValue {
    debugPrint("can fit")
} else {
    debugPrint("nope, cannot fit")
}
```

but... I think that other concepts are completely valid too.

Comment: No need to assign any value to your enumeration cases but if you would like to you can just assign the first value. All the rest would be inferred. `case small = 1, medium, large`

Comment: @LeoDabus, we don't need to but in this particular case it is a much better to do so.

Comment: Better is subjective. If you look at the Apple Swift book they have a very similar example where the only assign the first value.

Comment: it is _much better for OP_ – it is just a little people skills here.

Comment: It was just a comment. Of course it is much clearer to the OP. Just for the record. “By default, Swift assigns the raw values starting at zero and incrementing by one each time, but you can change this behavior by explicitly specifying values. In the example above, Ace is explicitly given a raw value of 1, and the rest of the raw values are assigned in order.”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 4.0.3).” iBooks. https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/the-swift-programming-language-swift-4-0-3/id881256329?mt=11

Comment: @LeoDabus, I know, I read the book too, I won't want to argue with that – my idea is about giving something extra beyond the dry technology.

Answer (score 4):

Well, “best” and “optimal” are subjective. My recommendation is to avoid [stringly-typed](http://wiki.c2.com/?StringlyTyped) programming. Use an `enum`.

I assume you'll get strings like `"small"` and `"large"` from an external source (maybe some JSON). If you make the `enum` using `String` as its raw value, it can parse the strings for you. Then you can add a `rank` property of some `Comparable` type like `Int` or `Double`, and use the `rank` to make the `enum` itself `Comparable`.

```
enum Size: String {
    case small
    case medium
    case large
}

extension Size: Comparable {
    var rank: Int {
        switch self {
        case .small: return 0
        case .medium: return 1
        case .large: return 2
        }
    }

    static func ==(_ a: Size, _ b: Size) -> Bool { return a.rank == b.rank }
    static func <(_ a: Size, _ b: Size) -> Bool { return a.rank < b.rank }
}

if let roomSize = Size(rawValue: "medium"), let sofaSize = Size(rawValue: "large") {
    if roomSize >= sofaSize {
        print("if it fits, I sits")
    } else {
        print("if the sofa don't fit, you must acquit")
    }
} else {
    print("what is this I don't even")
}
```

Comment: `var rank: Int {
        return hashValue
    }` or simply get rid of rank `static func ==(_ a: Size, _ b: Size) -> Bool { return a.hashValue == b.hashValue }
    static func <(_ a: Size, _ b: Size) -> Bool { return a.hashValue < b.hashValue }`

Comment: Why do you think `Size.small.hashValue < Size.medium.hashValue` or `Size.medium.hashValue < Size.large.hashValue`?